# Are questions about player management and logistics appropriate?

Tags: discussion

See title.  Assuming a subjective question can be avoided, is a question about managing players appropriate here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.  Plus random words to make the answer take.

Comment: I totally don't understand the second sentence.

Comment: @Adam - have you ever tried to enter a short answer here?  There is a minimum number of characters needed.

Comment: Exactly, there's a character limit so you can't just say "Yes."